# File not found on android device but found on android Emulator

Tags: android

I am working on an app that writes the response of a server in an xml file, created and saved on the device. 
In development, DDMS I can see and Use the file in `/data/data/my.package/files/test.xml`
Because I am trying to test something on a real device and don't want to make a request to the server I wanted to copy-paste by hand the test.xml in the device(tablet), like this:
`root/created data folder/created data folder/created my.package folder/created files folder/put my test.xml here`. Tried different options to put the test.xml in the same place with the .apk etc. I still get file not found on the device. 
In code I simply get the file like this:

```
context.openFileInput("test.xml"); // on the emulator works.
```

Should it look in `data/data/my.package/test.xml`?
If so, why on tablet if i create the same path in Android device shouldn't I find the file ?

I hope I wasn't confusing, any ideas would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have put it in /data/data/your.package/files/test.xml (note the `files` part)

Comment: I think yours should be the correct answer but it does not work,it still does not find the file. it's sure a stupid mistake of mine i cannot spot.thx

Comment: to check if your path is right, you may try to create a file from your application and make sure it appears in the same directory where you try to copy your other file. if you got your path right, it might be related to the android protection, which won't let you write files to the application directories on the real device.

Comment: if i create a file by code it creates it. but physically i cannot see that file in the explorer of android tablet. so yes, you are right, it's a matter of protection. Can i overpass this? thank you

Comment: i placed my xml in res/raw/ folder and then got access to it like this: `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);` which returns an InputStream. thx :)

Comment: you may also try to put your data files into `assets/` folder of your project and use `getAssets().open('filename')` to get access to them